# Как правильно оформить переменные?

Tags: java, android, code-style

Как с точки зрения правил оформления кода в java/android правильнее оформлять вот такой код?

```
public static final String
        COL_ID              = "id",
        COL_LAST_MOD        = "lastModificationDate",
        COL_OBJ_ID          = "objectId",
        KEY_SHOW_ALERT      = "SHOW_ALERT",
        TAG_TIMELINE_ITEM   = "TAG_TIMELINE_ITEM",
        TAG_FRAGMENT        = "TAG_FRAGMENT";
```

Или :

```
public static final String COL_ID = "id";
public static final String COL_LAST_MOD = "lastModificationDate";
public static final String COL_OBJ_ID = "objectId";
public static final String KEY_SHOW_ALERT = "SHOW_ALERT";
public static final String TAG_TIMELINE_ITEM = "TAG_TIMELINE_ITEM";
public static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "iTAG_FRAGMENTd";
```

Comment: Второй вариант.

Comment: Чисто из спортивного интереса - вы в первом варианте пробельчики  собираетесь вручную набивать?

Comment: Видимо, да. Ну а если их убрать, как лучше ?

Comment: только второй вариант, советую привыкнуть к такому стилю.
первый - тяжело поддерживать, любое форматирование кода может сломать ваш стиль